# Cómo puedo pasar este código de javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-blade

estoy usando un `for` en `javascript`

```
 var cadena = '<tr>'
     for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            cadena += `<td>${i}</td>` 
     }
     cadena += '</tr>'
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = cadena
```

ahora quiero pasar ese código a `php`

y estoy haciendo esto:

```
 @php
    $cadena = '<tr>';
        for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
            $cadena .= "<th>$i</th>";
        }
    $cadena .= '</tr>';
    // document.getElem.........
 @endphp
```

En `js` uso el `document.getE.....` para enviar al `DOM`, como lo haría con `php`?

y no he comprobado si esta correcto el `for`, si no lo esta agradecería también me corrijan y comenten eso.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres pasarlo a PHP?

Comment: estoy usando `dompdf` y no me permite usar `JS`, intente varias cosas que aconsejan para utilizar en `dompdf` pero al parecer no funcionan. entonces probé con `php` y aparentemente si funciona. y necesito hacer unas tablas dinámicas con `n` filas y columnas y tengo que ingeniármelas, por eso estoy intentando hacer lo que pido.

Comment: Ya. El problema es que JS está del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor. Para estos casos la mejor forma de comunicar entre cliente y servidor sería Ajax. Pero no necesitas pasar todo de JS a PHP,  puedes más bien usar PHP para construir el contenido HTML y para generar el PDF también. Quizá no siquiera necesites Ajax, salvo que quieras actualizar cosas de forma dinámica.

Comment: Si gracias, tocara hacerlo desde el controlador.